# Indesign paragraph style copy attributes from "based on"

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

I have an Indesign template with a paragraph style called **Main** defined as below:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, this style is "based on" yet another style called **Word** which is in a styles-folder called **Entry**. And this is just one of a dozen-odd styles, all "based on" other styles from that folder. In order to reduce the obvious clutter and redundancy, I wish to delete all styles defined in that folder and just retain the ones that are derived off of them. Is there any easy way to copy all style definitions from one style to another, e.g., from the style named **Entry** to the one named **Main** in this example?

Comment: Choosing "no style" for the "based on" causes the style to retain all formatting and break the link to the other existing style. Is this what you mean?

Comment: So in this case of I choose "no style" for the Main style's based on field, will it retain all attributes of the original Word style? Because that's what I want. I don't want it to revert to some default "base" style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose `No Style` for the `Based On` field all references to other styles get removed. However all *formatting* will be retained.

Based upon your question, I believe you can set the `Based On` to `No Style` and be set. This way all the original "Word (Entry)" style formatting will still be applied to "Main". However, if you change the "Word (Entry)" style, "Main" will no longer change as well.

You'll see the update in the `Style Settings` area once you set `Based On` to `No Style`.

If this does not do what you want, you can *duplicate the "Word(Entry)" style*, change it and title it "Main" -- same thing essentially.